# should I get rid of mutiple git installations, if so how? (OS X)

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, git, package-management

I hope the title isn't confusing, but I seem to have accumulated a couple of different versions of git in various directories over the years. I'd like to clean it all up and just have one version, and set that as the default.

`whereis git` gives me `/usr/bin/git`, `which git` gives me `/usr/local/bin/git`.

I've got another version under `/usr/local/Cellar/git` (version 2.16). Installed with Homebrew I guess

Then there's `/usr/local/git` (version 2.10) which is what what I get with `git --version` on terminal.

Comment: Is any of them a sym-link to the other?

Comment: I don't know. How do I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple different versions of Git.  One is `/usr/bin/git`, which is shipped with the system and is a wrapper around XCode's version.  Since you're using Homebrew, XCode (or at least its developer tools) is required, and you have Homebrew's version in `/usr/local/bin/git`.

The files under `/usr/local/Cellar` are the places that Homebrew stores files, and they will update automatically if you use Homebrew.  You should not modify or delete those files except by using the standard `brew` methods.

It's possible that you also have the prebuilt Git packages for macOS installed under `/usr/local/git`.  These are a little out of date, so you're probably better off getting rid of that directory and using Homebrew's instead, which is almost always the latest and most up-to-date version.

In order to use Homebrew's version over `/usr/bin/git`, set your PATH in your shell configuration to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, and you'll use Homebrew's version automatically.

Comment: Great! Thank you for this comment, exactly was I was after. BTW, how do I set the PATH as you described?

Comment: You'd edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshenv` (depending on your shell) and write something like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (depending on what you want to set it to).